# Laravel join using elquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

How do I do this SQL using Elquent where I have User Model using `users` table that hasMany relations on UserData `user_datas` table.

```
SELECT users.user_id
   , SUM(CASE WHEN user_datas.code_type = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Paused
   , SUM(CASE WHEN user_datas.code_type = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active
FROM users
    JOIN user_datas on users.user_id = user_datas.user_id
GROUP BY users.user_id
ORDER BY users.user_id ASC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** Please make sure User model is declared properly.

```
class User extends Model 
{
   public function userDatas(){
         return $this->hasMany(UserData::class, 'user_id');
   }

}
```

**Step2:** Please make sure UserData model is declared properly.

```
class UserData extends Model 
{
public function user(){
         return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
   }
}
```

**Step3:** Please edit the code in controller.

```
User::select('user_id')->withSum(
    ['userDatas as Paused' => function($query) {
        $query->where('code_type ', 'P');
    }],
    'code_type'
     )
    ->withSum(
    ['userDatas as Active' => function($query) {
        $query->where('code_type ', 'A');
    }],
    'code_type'
    )
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->orderBy('user_id', 'DESC')
```

Comment: With the above I get `ERROR: column user_datas.Paused does not exist`

Comment: Check the modified code please